# Azure DevOps: How to pass on a variable to a template read from Library variable group

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a variable group defined in pipeline > Library > variable group > called 'template-variable-group'

[image: Defining Variable Group in Azure DevOps]

All that I am trying to accomplish here is to pass on the value of the variable `my-temp-var` (in this case as you can see its value is `my-template-value`) to a template from the yaml file.

I have a yaml based pipeline as follows.

```
variables:
- group: template-variable-group

name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)

stages:
  - stage: Build

    jobs:
      - job: buildWebApp
        displayName: Build Release pipeline for Discount Service on Master branch

        steps:
        - script: |
            echo Here we go
          displayName: 'Command Line Script'

        - template: template.yaml
          parameters:
            variableToTemplate: ${{variables['my-temp-var']}}
```

And the template.yaml file is as follows.

```
parameters:
  variableToTemplate:

steps:

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
      echo ${{ parameters.variableToTemplate }}
  displayName: 'Run a two-line script'
```

I am not able to do that.

[image: pipeline with a template]

As you can see, that value is not reaching the template. What am I missing.

I saw this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64606274/1977871) but did not seem to be of help.

Comment: try to pass this: `${{ variables.my-temp-var }}` or `$(my-temp-var)`

Comment: Thank You @Shayki Abramczyk. The second one worked.

Comment: Great! I added it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass it like a regular variable:

```
$(my-temp-var)
```

Comment: That will not work. That will simply pass the literal '$(my-temp-var)' as the parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

Passing it this way $(my-temp-var) will only serve for printing the value somewhere. If you try to use it as a parameter to something say for an ssh connection, the passed value will not work. I am still exploring why but it does not wok.